# remove an element from the back of a vector after shuffling it c++

Tags: c++, vector, random, error-handling, shuffle

so the purpose of the code is to shuffle a vector, then print a random number from the vector, and then delete that same number so it won't repeat.
what I did is:

1. there is an initialized vector called songs, first I used random_device to make a random func.
2. I initialized an iterator to the back of the vector.
3. I shuffled the vector
4. Print
5. remove the last element that I printed (after shuffling).

The problem is when I do songs.pop_back(); it removes the last element from the original vector and not from the shuffled one, so it makes numbers coming back that way.
and I get an error.

code:

```
int getSong(int n, vector<int> songs, vector<int>::iterator iter) {
    random_device random;
    shuffle(songs.begin(), songs.end(), random);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << songs[j] << " ";
    }
    iter = songs.end() -1 ;
    int song = *iter;
    iter--;
    return song;
}
```

```
int main() {

    vector<int> songs = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int n = songs.size();
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; n--) {
        int l = getSong(n, songs, iter);
        cout << "The song number is:" << l << "\n" << endl;
        songs.pop_back();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Relearn about the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. In essense, you dropped a `&`.

Comment: `songs.back()` may be of interest.

Comment: @sweenish you right, I tried to make the vector global and it didn't work.
but It worked passing it by reference, thank you.

Comment: Why bother shuffling the whole vector?  Why not just pick a random index into the vector, and then remove that item?

Comment: @UKMonkey If the intent is to remove, this might be the easier approach. I also wanted to revisit this question and say the use of `std::random_device` is not ideal at all.

Comment: @UKMonkey it's more efficient you're right, can you post an example?

Comment: You'll find many examples of how to get a random number here (hint: don't use rand now).  You then just want to return `vec[myNumber]` and call `erase()` to remove the item.  You've got this, I've faith in you.  If you have issues, just ask a new question with the specific issue you've got and everyone will be happy to help (just make sure it's not a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this instead. It is sort of wasteful but I wanted to keep your original program structure.

First, you need to pass a reference to the vector with `std::vector<int>&` if you want to modify its contents in the function.  If your intent was to keep the original vector then yes, you just pass by value. But as you need to remove the last value in the main function, I figured this was the only way.

Second the iterator is not necessary. You can just remove that.

Last, you dont need to pass the size as the vector itself contains the size.

The use of `random_device` is somewhat awkward as `random_shuffle` would be cleaner - but again I tried to change your code minimally.

```cpp
int getSong( vector<int>& songs ) {
    random_device random;
    shuffle(songs.begin(), songs.end(), random);
    for ( int song : songs ) {
        cout << song << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return *songs.rbegin();
}
```

In regards to the main loop, checking for `empty()` is cleaner than a loop through the size - it's more immune to edge cases.

```cpp
int main() {
    vector<int> songs = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    while( !songs.empty() )  {
        int l = getSong(songs);
        cout << "The song number is:" << l << "\n" << endl;
        songs.pop_back();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oWbxvMjE3

Produces:

```
Program stdout

5 3 6 8 1 9 7 4 2 
The song number is:2

7 3 5 8 6 9 1 4 
The song number is:4

6 1 9 8 3 5 7 
The song number is:7

3 6 1 5 8 9 
The song number is:9

6 8 5 3 1 
The song number is:1

8 5 3 6 
The song number is:6

3 5 8 
The song number is:8

3 5 
The song number is:5

3 
The song number is:3
```

Comment: And maybe address the issue with how `random_device` is used, just for completeness.

Comment: Note that [`random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is removed since C++17 and shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: The answer is still missing a description of why the program used to crash and why the new code doesn't crash. It's because `iter--;` is not allowed if `iter` is already an iterator to the first element.